# AR Core uses-feature description on AndroidManifest.XML (Unity3D)

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-manifest, arcore

I am building an AR/Unity3D (.aab) to upload to Google Play. I receive the following error from the Google Developer Console: "The uses-feature android.hardware.camera.ar is required in in the AndroidManifest.xml file when a dependency on ARCore is specified as required." Please see attached screenshot.

I have reached the Manifest file, copied it to /Plugins/Android folder. Edited and added the following snippet:

```
<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.camera.ar"
android:required="true" />
```

I still get the same error from Google. What should I do to publish this build?

Answer (score 0):

Below lines worked for me in this case

```js
  
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
            android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
            android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full"
            android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.camera.ar"
            android:required="false" />
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.ar.core"
            android:value="optional" />
```